# Is there are relationship between the Ricci scalar and the determinant?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, tensor-calculus, curvature

On the one hand the determinant (technically the absolute value of the determinant) represents the "volume distortion" experienced by a region after being transformed.

On the other hand the scalar curvature represents the amount by which the volume of a small geodesic ball in a Riemannian manifold deviates from that of the standard ball in Euclidean space.

Is there a link between the two? Can the determinant of a matrix be interpreted as a scalar curvature? If I makes a difference, I am mostly interested in the context of general relativity.

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4481076/

Answer (score 9):

The determinant of the metric tensor $\det g $ is a scalar density of weight $+2$, and thus, when expressed in terms of local coordinates, transforms with the square of the Jacobian of the mapping.

It follows then that its value at a point provides no invariant measure of curvature content, since you can always e.g. rescale your coordinates and obtain larger and larger values of the determinant.

Nevertheless, it's extremely important - when its square root $\sqrt{-\det g} $ (density weight +1) is multiplied with a tensor density, a Levi-Civita symbol $\epsilon_{\alpha \beta \gamma \delta} $(symbol!), of opposite density weight, the result is an antisymmetric tensor field - a volume 4-form, also called a pseudo-Riemannian volume form.

$$ \eta = \sqrt{-\det g} dx^{0} \wedge dx^{1} \wedge dx^{2} \wedge dx^{3} $$

$$ \eta = \frac{1}{4!} \sqrt{-\det g} \;\epsilon_{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta} dx^{\alpha} \wedge dx^{\beta} \wedge dx^{\gamma} \wedge dx^{\delta} $$

If you use a definition of the exterior product with a suitable factor in front, the above is equal to:

$$ \eta =  \sqrt{-\det g} \;\epsilon_{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta} dx^{\alpha} \otimes dx^{\beta} \otimes dx^{\gamma} \otimes dx^{\delta} $$

Now, such an entity can be integrated in a coordinate invariant manner to provide a measure of volume.

$$ V = \int \eta$$

EDIT:

It has been recognised in the comment that it's not really a good answer, and I agree.

I will therefore derive the only correspondence that I can think of now. The other one would relate the second Lie derivative of the volume form $\mathcal{L}_{X}\mathcal{L}_{X}\eta$, which could be massaged into a form that involves a Ricci tensor, but this is pretty arbitrary, as anything that involves second covariant derivatives could have that.

**The expansion of the metric determinant in normal coordinates around a point $p$ involves the Ricci tensor. This is essentially the claim present in your question.**

To derive this, we shall be using the known result of the expansion of the metric tensor in normal (Riemann) coordinates. The result can be found stated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2896648/the-taylor-expansion-of-a-metric-a-natural-viewpoint), [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/379629/taylor-expansion-of-the-metric-tensor-in-the-normal-coordinates), or [here](https://cuhkmath.wordpress.com/2012/03/16/taylor-expansion-of-metric/).

The statement is that in normal coordinates around a point p, the following expansion holds:

$$ g_{\mu\nu}(\gamma(t)) = \delta_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{3}t^{2} R_{\mu\alpha\nu\beta}\dot{\gamma}^{\alpha}\dot{\gamma}^{\beta} - \frac{1}{6}t^{4}R_{\mu\alpha\nu\beta;\sigma}\dot{\gamma}^{\alpha}\dot{\gamma}^{\beta}\dot{\gamma}^{\sigma} + \mathcal{O}(t^{6})$$

If we expand the metric determinant along a curve $x=\gamma(t)$, we will get:

$$ \det g_{\mu\nu} (\gamma(t)) = \det g_{\mu\nu} (\gamma(0)) + t (\partial_{t}\det g_{\mu\nu})(\gamma(0)) + \frac{1}{2}t^{2}(\partial^{2}_{t}\det g_{\mu\nu})(\gamma(0))  + \mathcal{O}(t^{3})$$

The rule for the derivative of the determinant is:

$$ \partial_{t}\det g_{\mu\nu}(\gamma(t)) =(\det g_{\mu\nu})(\gamma(t))\; g^{\mu\nu}((\gamma(t))\;(\partial_{t}g_{\mu\nu})(\gamma(t)) $$

and thus, evaluating at $t=0$:

$$ (\partial_{t}\det g_{\mu\nu})(\gamma(0)) = (\det g_{\mu\nu})(\gamma(0))\; g^{\mu\nu}((\gamma(0))\;(\partial_{t}g_{\mu\nu})(\gamma(0))=0$$

because $\partial_{t}g_{\mu\nu}(\gamma(0))=0$.

EDIT2:
One needs to take the second derivative wrt. to the parameter $t$. See the powers of $t$ provided in the blog post and copied by me above.

Second derivative reads:

$$ \partial^{2}_{t}\det g_{\mu\nu}(\gamma(t)) =\partial_{t}(\det g_{\mu\nu})(\gamma(t))\; g^{\mu\nu}((\gamma(t))\;(\partial_{t}g_{\mu\nu})(\gamma(t)) + \\ 
(\det g_{\mu\nu})(\gamma(t))\; (\partial_{t}g^{\mu\nu})((\gamma(t))\;(\partial_{t}g_{\mu\nu})(\gamma(t)) \\
+  (\det g_{\mu\nu})(\gamma(t))\; g^{\mu\nu}((\gamma(t))\;(\partial^{2}_{t}g_{\mu\nu})(\gamma(t))$$

If we evaluate second derivative at $t=0$, we see that the $\partial_{t}\det g_{\mu\nu}$ contribution vanishes by virtue of the previous calculation. Same holds for $\partial_{t}g^{\mu\nu}$, which is (using $g_{\mu\nu}g^{\nu\sigma} = \delta^{\sigma}_{\mu}$ and differentiating both sides) equal to:

$$\partial_{t}g^{\mu\nu} = -g^{\mu\alpha}g^{\nu\beta}\partial_{t}g_{\alpha\beta}$$

and, involving $\partial_{t}g_{\alpha\beta}$ as well, vanishes at $t=0$.

Therefore the only contribution to the $\partial^{2}_{t}\det g_{\mu\nu}$ that can be non-zero comes from the part with $\partial^{2}_{t}g_{\mu\nu}$. From the metric expansion, differentating twice and evaluating at $t=0$ leaves only the term with the Riemann tensor contracted with the curve velocity vectors, and the factor of $2$ cancels the $\frac{1}{2}$ in the $\det g_{\mu\nu}$ Taylor expansion.

At long last it holds that up to quartic terms:

$$ \det g_{\mu\nu} (\gamma(t)) = 1 - \frac{1}{3}\,t^{2}\,R_{\alpha\beta}\dot{\gamma}^{\alpha}\dot{\gamma}^{\beta} + \mathcal{O}(t^{4})$$

Comment: This is a very nice answer but it doesn't mention the Ricci scalar at all